# StreamDensityPlot creating an Image that doesn't correspond to DensityPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am trying to use StreamPlotDensity to find the direction of my electric field at a point x,y. My electric field is given as

```
ElecticField={((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + y^2) Cos[2 Pi])^2 + ((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + y^2) Cos[2 Pi])^2}
```

Now when I use PlotDensity for this electric field with the code

```
 DensityPlot[{((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + y^2) Cos[2 Pi])^2 + ((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + y^2) Cos[2 Pi])^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Minimal", 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

To get

[image]

Now when I use the following StreamDensityPlot code

```
StreamDensityPlot[{((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + y^2) Cos[
     2 Pi]), ((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + y^2) Cos[2 Pi])}, {x, -3, 
  3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Minimal", PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

I get the image

[image]

Now my issue is that the image is not showing the direction lines for all parts of the plot and that the plot is not looking how the DensityPlot one does. Can you please provide some help regarding this

Essentially what I am trying to do is create a plot of my electric field and show the direction of it at a point x,y.

Thank you for all your help

Comment: Look at the velocity field in "StreamDensityPlot". The x and y component are identical. Therefore you get diagonal stream lines.

Comment: @DanielHuber, Thank you for your answer, I am not totally sure what you mean by the x and y component are exactly the same. Could you please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: The vector in "StreamPlot": `t = {((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + y^2) Cos[
      2 Pi]), ((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + y^2) Cos[2 Pi])};
t[[1]] == t[[2]]` has identical x and y components

Comment: Thank you @DanielHuber I understand the issue now.